# How do I make a search filter that you can only search for a specifc element within a set of divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, filter

Currently, I am able to search for a hall by typing anything that is within a hall container (including name, location, capacity), however, I only want to be able to filter results for searches for a hall name.

```
<div id="searchFilter" class="flexColumn">
      <label for="searchFilterText">Search for Community Halls</label>
      <input type="text" id="searchFilterText" placeholder="Search for the name of a community hall">
</div>

`<div class="hall">
      <div class="info">
          <p>${data.Halls[halls[i]].Location[0].Address}, ${data.Halls[halls[i]].Location[1].Suburb}<br>Capacity: ${data.Halls[halls[i]].Room[0]["Standing Capacity"]}</p> 
      </div>
      <div class="image">
          <img class="img" src="${data.Halls[halls[i]].Description[4].Photos}" alt="${data.Halls[halls[i]]["Hall Name"]}">
      </div>
      <div class="hallNameBox">
           <p class="hallName">${data.Halls[halls[i]]["Hall Name"]}</p>
      </div>
 </div>`;

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchFilterText").on("keyup", function() {
    let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".hall").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: You can check if after filter if none of the div are visible then you can show all .hall div  which means user has not typed hallname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `toggle` use `show` and `hide`.

(Use `one`, `two`, or `three` to test this reduced example).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#searchFilterText").on('keyup', function() {

    // Grab the value
    const value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    // If it's not empty
    if (value) {

      // `filter` all the hall elements if
      // the text of the hallName element doesn't start with
      // the value and hide them
      $('.hall').filter(function() {
        const text = $(this).find('.hallName').text().toLowerCase();
        return !text.startsWith(value);
      }).hide();

    // Otherwise show them
    } else {
      $('.hall').show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="searchFilter" class="flexColumn">
<input type="text" id="searchFilterText" />
</div>

<div class="hall">
  <div class="hallNameBox">
    <p class="hallName">One</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hall">
  <div class="hallNameBox">
    <p class="hallName">Two</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="hall">
  <div class="hallNameBox">
    <p class="hallName">Three</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#searchFilterText").on("keyup", function() {
    let value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $(".hall *").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

Is this what you want? If not, let me know.

Comment: No sorry. I need to only be able to input a hall name and for the ones that don't match, the entire hall div is removed. If the capacity or location is searched for, nothing should happen.

Comment: it just deletes all of the hall names when you try to search. i don't know if I have been specific enough in what I want to do.

Comment: not exactly. here is what it looks like: https://imgur.com/JKjNDap
I want the acacia ridge hall box to have everything inside it when you search for it and for those black boxes to disappear and only see the halls that match the search (which is only one in this case).